# How to find N highest numbers in array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, .net

I needed to write a function that finds N highest numbers in an array.

I tried nothing. Don't even know where to start.

```
public int marathon(int input1,int input2, int[] input3)
{
    //  this is the function, ignore first input its not relevant input 2 is 
    //  N(How much highest numbers you want from array )
}
```

If you put 2 as input2 and array looks like this {1,2,3,4} output will be 3 and 4

Comment: Sort the array descending, and take the first `X` items from the list: `var results = input3.OrderByDescending(n => n).Take(input2).ToList();` Do you want to return them in the original order, or was that incidental?

Answer (score 2):

A little lambda will do the trick.

```
var top = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }.OrderByDescending(num => num).Take(N);
```

Answer (score 0):

By LINQ: Simply sort the array and take the first N items. Example of an extension method to do that:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> TakeHighests<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection, int count)
    {
        return collection.OrderByDescending(i => i) // Sort the enumerable (arrays are also enumerables). Use OrderBy() for N lowest items
            .Take(count) // Take only `count` items
    }
}
```

Sample using of taking 2 highest values:

```
int[] arr = ...;
int[] twoHighests = arr.TakeHighests(2).ToArray();
```